# Hunting a spooky offline.html

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, offlineapps

I once wrote a quick ‘offline.html‘. Just be be sure I understood how offline PWA worked:

```
This is offline.html (My App Name)
```

I thought it worked as expected. So I deleted it and wrote a better one, with a back button, some info etc.

Now when this app is offline it starts on the page the manifest.json days, as expected.

However, if I try to refresh the page that spooky "offline.html" shows up. From nowhere.

I've tried to understand where it lurks, but I can't find it. (The new "offline.htmi" is there when I go to it in the web browser.)

I've tried Firefox offline on my mobile to see if the spoky "offline.html" jumps up there to. It does.

I've cleared the cache in Chrome. The spoky "offline.html" is still there.

Any ideas?

(This is on Android 9)

Comment: Have you been able to resolve it by unregistering the service worker and reinstalling it?

Comment: @none I have not had time yet. A quick check on my Android mobile gave a 404 on `.update()` for the registered service worker. Looks like a Chrome bug to me, some leftover. I will dig a bit.

Comment: Just tried this for my app to see if it works and it does after i cleared my cache, `navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js', {
                        scope: './'
                    }).then(function(reg) {
                        console.log('Service worker has been registered');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            reg.update();
                        },10000)
                    });  `

Comment: @none And yes, there is an old service worker. Another file is registered.

Comment: @none Clearing cache and `.update()` did not remove the old service worker for me.

Comment: @none And the file for the registered service worker is not on the server. (There is a 404 for trying to read it. Just checking if there is something strange with ‘.update()‘.)

Comment: Nah, that strange, can you put me more in the picture, I'm too blinded out to assist, share the script that registers the service worker!

Comment: I think I deleted the old service worker file, but I can dig it up in the GIT history, of course. But I do not think it is necessary right now. The strange thing is that Chrome holds on to a deleted service worker file. I am not sure why. I think it is a bug. At the moment I will try to unregister it after `.update()` fails.

Comment: @none Thanks for your help. I have added an answer with my current version for setting up the service worker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198119/discussion-between-none-and-leo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offline pages are not exactly stored in caches as regular cached items, there are stored quite differently, relative to the current installed service worker. I tried looking for an article to explain this more but can't walk around any currently.

However you'll have to  [unregister your service worker](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache/issues/340) or learn how [Updating service worker works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update),

The aim is to remove the lurking offline.html served to the new offline.html that exists.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my answer for what I finally decided to use.

Comment: Cool, But do you really mean to update your service worker anytime user is online?

Comment: Yes, it is the simplest way right now. (It is of course better using a `fetch()` `HEAD` request, but I expect the standards to take care of this later.)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I finally landed on. It seems to work. The test for 404 is of course not optimal, but I leave it that way for now, hoping that the emerging standard will address this issue soon.

```
async function setupServiceWorker() {
  let reg;
  if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    console.log("Active service worker found, no need to register");
    // new Popup("registered service worker, .active.scriptURL", reg.active.scriptURL, null, true).show();
    reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();
  } else {
    reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("service-worker.js", { scope: "./" });
    console.log("Service-worker.js registered, scope: " + reg.scope);
  }
  try {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
      const newReg = await reg.update();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    const is404 = err.message.match("404");
    new Popup("err", is404 + " " + err.message).show();
    if (is404) {
      let wasUnregistered;
      try {
        wasUnregistered = await reg.unregister();
      } catch (errUnreg) {
        new Popup("unregister() service worker failed", errUnreg.message).show();
      }
      if (wasUnregistered) {
        setTimeout(setupServiceWorker, 1000);
      }
    }
  }
}
setTimeout(setupServiceWorker, 5000);
```